# How do I suggest to protect one of my question

Tags: support, specific-question, protected-questions

Since I don't have the reputation to protect my own question (or maybe just don't know how...), I was wondering **if there is a way to suggest** to those who can to protect [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391503/a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-conne/31712406#31712406)? I think there is more than enough answers and accepted answer has been upvoted several times. There is no need for more "0 upvoted" answer.

I've seen a lot of question with the "This question is protected", which I think is a good mechanism to prevent a question to have too many bad quality answers when a good answer has been given a long time ago.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can flag for a moderator using the "Other" flag reason, bring up your question here on Meta, or ask in a chat room related to the topic (so it will be likely to have 15k users).

Just make sure your question meets the criteria that will make protecting it worthwhile. Protecting a question only prevents new answers from users with less than 10 reputation, so if you're not getting a lot of those "drive-by" answers, it's not really going to accomplish anything.

In this case, I see that there are several deleted answers and low-scoring answers from new users who were just reporting that they had the same problem, so I went ahead and protected your question. (If I remember correctly, I think there's a script that protects questions automatically if enough of these kinds of answers are deleted, but some of these are old and might have been deleted before that script was put in place.)